# Angular2 UI router -ng2 routing from the controller

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

So I am using the UI-Router ng2 and I am trying to change route after a function happen, my code seems like this:

```
SomeFuncion() {
    if(something){
        router.goto('/newRouteName');
    }
}
```

using the router from the HTML is simple with the uiSref but, I got no clue how to route from inside the component with the new ng2 router, thier doc didn't help much.

Answer (score 4):

Inject the `StateService` in your component.

```
import { StateService } from "ui-router-ng2";

@Component({})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(public stateService: StateService) {}

  goSomewhere() {
    this.stateService.go('somewhere');
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems the latest syntax is import {StateService} from '@uirouter/core';

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this. My example is in Typescript

```
class SomeComponent {

   constructor(router: Router) {
      if(something) router.navigate(['/SomeRoute']);
   }
}
```

Comment: what should i import in order to use it?
for uiSref use i import UIRouterDirectives.
what should i import for the action from the constructor

Comment: this is angular 2 example i'll edit the answer and add angular 1 example

Comment: i dont think you understood what i meant :P
i am working in angular 2,
just searching for the import i need in order to use ng2-uirouter state.go